# Sending Params Correctly without Interpolation with Splat

Tags: powershell, invoke, splat

Can I directly import these parameters to my function with their correct types **with only value** with respectively?

```
$appparams = @{ 
    sname  = "RandomAppName"    # type: string
    sdata  = [byte]12           # type: Byte
    sgroup = $null              # type: NULL
}
```

**CASE:** not sending as respectively + not correct types

```
$arglist = ($appparams.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | % { "$($_.Value)" }) -join ','
Invoke-Function .... $arglist  -> Invoke-Function .... 12,,RandomAppName
```

**Expected**: sending only value with respectively and without any interpolation

```
Invoke-Function .... $arglist  -> Invoke-Function .... "RandomAppName",12,$null
```

Comment: [about splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting): `Invoke-Function @appparams`

Comment: As an aside, if "as respectively" means "in the same order", you can use an ```OrderedDictionary``` instead of a ```hashtable``` - e.g. ```$appparams = [ordered] @{ ... }``` - which will maintain the order of entries during enumeration. I think you probably want to look at splatting per @iRon's comment to solve your actual problem though...

Comment: No, Invoke-Function :S because its my custom function, I edited my post to avoid confusion. @iRon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **looks like you're trying to pass the *values* of your [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) entries as *positional* arguments to `Invoke-Function`**.

- This contrasts with the usual **hashtable-based [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)** that uses *named* arguments, where the *key* of each entry implies the target parameter, and the *value* the argument.
- In other words:

  - If `Invoke-Function` declared parameters named `-sname`, `-sdata`, and `-sgroup` with matching data types, you could use `Invoke-Function @appParams` to pass your hashtable as-is (except for using `@` instead of `$`, for splatting).
  - Since the parameter binding would then based on *names*, the fact that a `[hashtable]` (`@{ ... }`) instance's entries are inherently *unordered* would then *not* a problem, and no sorting is needed.
- **If you get to control the definition of `Invoke-Function` and it takes a known set of arguments** (as opposed to an open-ended list of arguments not known in advance), it is **best to make it [declare parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) and use hashtable-based splatting**, as described.

---

**If you cannot modify the target command and must pass arguments *positionally*:**

First, as [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, you need an *ordered* hashtable (`[ordered]`) if the definition order of the entries (values) must be maintained (see below for an alternative based on sorting by keys, as you've tried).

Then you can use ***array*-based splatting** to *positionally* pass your hashtable's values:

```bash
# *Sample function* that simply echoes its positional arguments
# and their types.
# This serves as a *stand-in* for *your* function of that name.
function Invoke-Function { $args | ForEach-Object { $isNull = $null -eq $_; [pscustomobject] @{ Value = if ($isNull) { '$null' } else { $_ }; Type = if (-not $isNull) { $_.GetType() } } } }

# The ordered hashtable whose values are to be passed as positional arguments.
$appParams = [ordered] @{ 
    sdata  = [byte]12           # type: Byte
    sgroup = $null              # type: NULL
    sname  = "RandomAppName"    # type: string
}

# Get the ordered hashtable's values, as an *array*.
[array] $appParamValues = $appParams.Values

# Pass the values as separate, positional arguments.
Invoke-Function @appParamValues
```

Note:

- If you want to pass the array of values *as an array*, i.e. as a *single*  argument, simply replace `@` with `$`, i.e. pass the array as-is:

  ```bash
  # Pass the values as a *single argument* that is an *array*.
  Invoke-Function $appParamValues

  # *If* your function expects that single argument to be passed
  # as a *named* argument to parameter -ArgumentList
  Invoke-Function -ArgumentList $appParamValues
  ```
- If you don't get to control the creation of the hashtable and must indeed use sorting by key, define `$appParameterValues` as follows:

  ```bash
  $appParamValues = 
    $appParams.Keys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { $appParams[$_] }
  ```

Output:

```bash
Value         Type
-----         ----
RandomAppName System.String
12            System.Byte
$null
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `($appparams.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | % { "$($_.Value)" }) -join ','`

This:

- *stringifies* all values due to use of string interpolation (`"..."`)
- due to `-join ','` creates a *single string* value that is the `,`-separated list of all stringified values.

This results both in loss of the original data types and loss of separate values, and would be seen by any target command as a *single string argument*, as described.

Comment: By the way, I think [ordered] for PSv3+, I wonder if there is an alternative solution for powershell v2?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, in v2 you can use the .NET type underlying `[ordered]` explicitly (which is more cumbersome, because there's no literal syntax): [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki, "*I think it was a great question for me*", it would be better if it was a great question for others too. For that, I would expect some background of this foreign "custom function". It does have the PowerShell Verb-Noun naming, yet it apparently can't be threathed as such. What is this "custom fuction?" What is the use case. Why can't 
you use the normal [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)? With this infomation you might even receive more complete answers or stable solutions than ***you***  imaging.